# php - unset current http headers that my php file send and replace with custom one

Tags: php, http, http-headers

setting custom header in PHP is available with `header();` function but i want to unset all the headers that being sent from my PHP file to the browser and write my own headers something like

```
unset(headers());    
$headers = array(
'Accept' => '',
'Content-Type' => '',
..etc
);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php

Comment: that only removes the headers that have been made by PHP like "X-Powered-By: Php*" not all headers

Comment: Thinkig, it is all availiable

Comment: Well, what additional headers do you want to unset?

Comment: All O.o and add my own headers I want to do that bcoz in my framework be able to edit the headers and when script runs it set default defined headers or the edited one

Comment: you can use like this: header("Location: http://www.example.com"); or header("Expires: Sat, 22 Dec 1979 05:30:00 GMT"); and then use headers_sent() to check if headers are already sent or not